# Allow access to folder which is inside the \application\ folder in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I was wondering, how i could give access to the public to files placed within a folder called 'Sample' which is placed inside /applications/views/ .

I tried to to do it using .htaccess file.

This is the **.htaccess** file that im using right now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /0.9.1

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Enable access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|application\views\Sample\/public)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your public files should be placed in `./assets` and not `./application` nothing should ever be served to the browser from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Are you placing your images, css, js etc in your application folder?  If you are **stop right there**.  The application and system folder don't allow direct script access and it should be kept that way.  Anything you want to make public you should put into a folder called something like public and place that in root directory alongside your application and system directories.

Comment: Hmmmm...i kind of got around it . But, im stuck at something else now. I posted another related question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697996/dynamic-folders-in-uploadfive-with-codeigniter I would be thankful if you could help me out there. I like how you used bold in your reply. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks, applying bold is a fine art